# full object binding with ember select view

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

So I'm building a component tied to a hasMany relation on an ember data model. I have a search modal that I'm popping up, and I just want to take the result of the search and use addObject to add the model to the relationship.

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  // relation is set when the controller is set up
  actions: {
    pushSelection(selection) {
      this.get('relation').addObject(selection);
    }
  }
});
```

So If I do the most basic form of an ember select, this works fine:

```
{{view "select"
  content=results 
  value=selection
  class="form-control"}}
<button type="button" {{action pushSelection selection}}>Make Selection</button>
```

The above works, but the select is full of ember internal instance names and not at all acceptable.

If I set optionLabelPath, it immediately stops working and selection int he action is undefined. I have tried, I think, every possible combination of value, objectLabelPath, optionValuePath and selection.

```
//reference selection by ID
{{view "select"
  content=results 
  value=selection.id
  optionValuePath='content.id'
  optionLabelPath='content.text'
  class="form-control"}}

//try just binding to whatever object
{{view "select"
  content=results 
  value=selection
  optionValuePath='content.id'
  optionLabelPath='content.text'
  class="form-control"}}

//don't bind the value of the option to the id
{{view "select"
  content=results 
  value=selection
  optionLabelPath='content.text'
  class="form-control"}}

//trying with the selection option instead
{{view "select"
  content=results 
  selection=selection
  optionValuePath='content.id'
  optionLabelPath='content.text'
  class="form-control"}}
```

I've done this sort of thing with the select2 addon before, which is nice, but this is for an addon and I don't really want to add that dependency if I can avoid id.

Comment: 1) Check your `results`, it should be an array of objects: `[{id: 1, text: 'Text'}, {id: 2, text: 'Text 2'}]`
2) Try `selectionBinding`

Comment: results is an array of ember data objects returned by this.store.findQuery

Comment: [Ember select is the devil](https://youtu.be/ltzN4v-ymo4?t=1h39m35s)